# Непонятный результат вычислений в Java

Tags: java

```
float step = 1.0047679f

int a = -56,  b = 10,  c = 1;

a += step;
b -= step;
c -= step;

a: -54
b: 8
c: 0
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему получились такие результаты вычислений?

Comment: Где-то что-то с приведением типов...

Comment: Да, если я буду приводить типы к примеру a += (int)step то все ок. Мне непонятно, почему он не приводит тип автоматически и почему значение увеличивается или уменьшается на 2 в разном случае

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При преобразовании значения с плавающей запятой в значение `int` дробная часть отбрасывается по направлению к 0. Поэтому при вычислении

```
c -= step;
```

что эквивалентно

```
c = c - step;
```

выражение в правой части имеет значение

```
1 - 1.0047679f равное где-то -0.0047679f
```

и при отбрасывании дробной части по направлению к нулю, когда значение присваивается `c` получается `0`.

В свою очередь для выражения

```
b -= step;
```

которое эквивалентно

```
b = b - step;
```

имеем

```
10 - 1.0047679f  равное где-то 8.9952321f
```

и при отбрасывании дробной части по направлению к нулю, когда значение присваивается `b` получается `8`.

Для выражения

```
a += step;
```

имеет место следующее вычисление

```
-56 + 1.0047679f  равное где-то -54.9952321f
```

В результате при отбрасывании дробной части по направлению к нулю получаем, что `a` будет равным `-54`.

Точно такой же результат вы получите и в C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float step = 1.0047679f;

    int a = -56, b = 10, c = 1;
    a += step; b -= step; c -= step;

    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << std::endl;
}    


a = -54, b = 8, c = 0
```

и в C#

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float step = 1.0047679f;

        int a = -56, b = 10, c = 1;
        a = (int)(a + step); b = (int)(b - step); c = (int)(c - step);

        Console.WriteLine( "a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ", c = " + c );
    }
}

a = -54, b = 8, c = 0
```

потому что правила округления совпадают.

Comment: т.е получается, что преобразование значения в тип int производится уже после операции сложения или вычитания. Понятно, Спасибо!

Comment: @user189541, если ответ вас устроил, не забудьте отметить его как принятый.

Comment: @user189541  Так как в операции присутствует операнд с плавающей запятой, то операнд с типом int преобразуется к типу с плавающей запятой. Затем при присваивании объекту типа int результата операции дробная часть отбрасывается.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что `c -= step` не эквивалентно `c = c - step`, а эквивалентно `c = (int)(c - step)`. Просто `c = c - step` — это ошибка компиляции в Java.